# How do I get my loop to stop iterating so that it stops when error is 10^-6

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code for newtons method finds the root of my equation, however, it iterates it 1000 times (which is supposed to be the maximum iteration). I want my program to stop iterating when the error is 10^-6

```html
from math import *
x = 100
for iteration in range(1, 1001):
    xnew = x - (((3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))))-1)/(.12*(3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5))))*(1-exp(-.12*x)*(-.12*x))) # the Newton-Raphson's formula
    if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
        break
    x = xnew  
print('The root : %0.5f' % xnew)
print('The number of iterations : %d' % iteration)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop, and increment the iteration counter explicitly instead:

```
from math import *
x = 100
iteration = 1
while True:
    xnew = x - (((3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5)))*(1-exp(-.12*x))))-1)/(.12*(3*10**-5)*exp((log1p(10**3/(3*10**-5))))*(1-exp(-.12*x)*(-.12*x))) # the Newton-Raphson's formula
    if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
        break
    x = xnew
    iteration += 1
print('The root : %0.5f' % xnew)
print('The number of iterations : %d' % iteration)
```

Comment: However, how would I do this if I want the max iterations to be 1000.

Comment: Then your original code is fine. It just won't reach the desired error margin within 1000 iterations mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the maximum iteration to be 1000, that's what you already have.  You did fine.  The problem -- if any -- is that your algorithm didn't converge to that error level.  Add in a tracing `print` statement:

```
print(x-xnew, x, xnew)
if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
    break
```

and look at the last lines of output:

```
5.5605395585800466e-05 7.6720967510363405 7.672041145640755
5.53221626899969e-05 7.672041145640755 7.671985823478065
5.504038345183204e-05 7.671985823478065 7.671930783094613
```

As you can see in the earlier answer (if you run the code), your algorithm doesn't converge until iteration 1790:

```
The root : 7.66133
The number of iterations : 1790
```